Why can't I set the visibility of an 3D object to true or false?

The method runs smoothly inside the agent, but it is on the main agent that it seems it doesn't seem to pick up what's happening inside the train agent.
train.color = 1;
((Headway)train).train_2.setVisible(false);

train_2 is green
train_3 is yellow
train_4 is red
I even tried an alternate approach, where I set the visibility of the 3D objects (train_2,3,4) to color==color1/2/3 based on necessity. That seems to have not worked either. As all three trains become visible.
Another approach I made, from the main agent I did
train.train_2.setColor(Material Name, Color) this also failed.

Should work, what is train_2? A group? Share some more details. And most importantly: Try to replicate with a trivial toy model (1 TrainEnter block with 1 train shown in 3D). Find the root cause :)

train_2, train_3, train_4 are the names of the 3D object. I am trying on a small model. Will let you know.

Hello Sir Benjamin, can you please tell how can i get access to my RailCar from a trainMoveTo block. I can access my train using train.somecode.
But I am not being able to access my RailCar.

pls learn to use the help, here are the API calls you can do on train: https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/rail-library/train.html#functions
Oh, and code-complete: if you type train. then Ctrl+space, you get all possible calls :)

I did check, there is no such calls to get access to railCar from train.

"getCar(int i) Returns a car with a given index. the first car index is 0, the last car — size()-1." --> so train.getCar(...) :)

Thanks and in order get your solution to work, the first thing I had to do was make sure my Train and RailCar was properly defined in every stage, including how the agent is intended to be used.

You need to specify which RailCars should be (in)visible. You need to add the method getCar(int i) after the Train agent (in your case, apparently the Headway agent), to get the RailCar agent that has the 3D object. The train agent should not have 3D objects representing RailCars, let the 3D representation of a RailCar only in the RailCar agent.
